AEM Page Exporter - Doesn't include components with multifields
I'm trying to export a page with the default model exporter of AEM. This page contains multiple components and some of them have multifields. When I visit homepage.model.json the JSON doesn't have the multifields.
carousel: {
    :type: "mysite/components/public/carousel",
    title: "Test title"
}

I've searched everywhere for a solution. Everywhere on the internet they suggest to make an Exporter for my component:
@Model(adaptables = Resource.class,
        defaultInjectionStrategy = DefaultInjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL,
        resourceType = {"mysite/components/public/carousel"})
@Exporter(name = "jackson", extensions = "json")

public class CarouselModelImpl implements CarouselModel, ComponentModel {

...
@Getter
    private List<CarouselBean> slides;
...

So when I visit
homepage/jcr:content/carousel.model.json I get the correct JSON:
{
    title: "Test title",
    slides: [
    {
        title: "slide title 1",
        description: null,
        ctaLabel: "cta label",
        ctaLink: "#",
        image: "/content/dam/mysite/Rectangle 2.png"
    },
    {
        title: "slide title 2",
        description: null,
        ctaLabel: "cta label",
        ctaLink: "#",
        image: "/content/dam/mysite/image.png"
    }
    ],
}

But when I visit the homepage.model.json it's still not included:
carousel: {
    :type: "mysite/components/public/carousel",
    title: "Test title"
}

So from what I understand I have 2 options:

To make a Page Exporter and have a lot of custom code.

Accept that I can't have a page with all the JSON data that I want.


I tried to make a custom Page Exporter with the logic to iterate all the children and sub-children in order to get the correct JSON with minimal code. I try to get the Exporter Models for each component, but the modelFactory is null.
@Model(adaptables = Resource.class,
        defaultInjectionStrategy = DefaultInjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL,
        resourceType = {"mysite/components/public/structure/public-page"})
@Exporter(name = "jackson", extensions = "json")
public class PageExporterServlet {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PageUtils.class);

    @Reference
    private ModelFactory modelFactory;

    @Reference
    private SlingScriptHelper slingScriptHelper;

    @Self
    private Resource resource;

    @Getter
    private String myTitle = "Test";

    @Getter
    Map<String, Object> pageData = new HashMap<>();

    @PostConstruct
    // PostConstructs are called after all the injection has occurred, but before the Model object is returned for use.
    protected void init() {
        try {
            processResource(resource, pageData);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.debug(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void processResource(Resource resource, Map<String, Object> pageData) {
        if (resource != null) {
            Iterable<Resource> childResources = resource.getChildren();
            for (Resource childResource : childResources) {
                ComponentModel componentModel = (ComponentModel) modelFactory.getModelFromResource(childResource);
                if (componentModel != null) {
                    pageData.put(childResource.getPath(), componentModel.getData());
                } else {
                    // If the resource is not a component, recursively process its children
                    processResource(childResource, pageData);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Your class is a Sling Model, not an OSGi service, so I wouldn't expect the @Reference annotation to work in this context. This is probably why it's coming up as null. To inject an OSGi service into a Sling Model, you'd need the @OSGiService injector-specific annotation.
@OSGiService
private ModelFactory modelFactory;

Also, you don't necessarily need to use a ModelFactory in this context. That's useful when injecting external resources based on a path. For child resources in a Sling Model, there are more convenient APIs available. There could be some edge cases around null-safety depending on what the models do exactly and how you want to handle validation, but this should work just fine for simple cases:
@ChildResource
List<ComponentModel> slides;

